# De Morgan's Law in Semantics what decides the rhs and lhs

Tags: semantics

We take a LHS and RHS in De Morgan's Law. How do we decide upon it?
How do we know which one to take as RHS and which one as LHS?

Comment: What notation are you using? In most common (infix) notations, it is clear, because the operator divides the operands. If you are using a Polish or Reverse Polish notation, there will be other syntactic mechanisms for delineating them. Your question as posed is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different kinds of [logical notation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-LogicalNotation.pdf) possible; few  worry about RHS or LHS.
Here are some different notational [conventions for De Morgan's Laws](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/demorgan.pdf), taken from this 
[Logic Study Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf). It doesn't refer to RHS vs LHS, because logical equivalence is symmetric.